# Is relating (image) table with (user), (product), (company) and any independent tables advised?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm thinking about having one `image` table to store images of any other independent table like `user`, `product` and so... (of course any single instances of independent tables (like `John Smith` as a `user`, and `laptop` as a `product`) may have 0, 1, or multiple `image`s.

The `image` table has `id`, `title` and `filename`.

And I'm thinking an `imagetable` table to relate `image`s to their proper `image owner`s like `user` with these fields: `image_id`, `table_id` and `table`.

Some entries might look like this:

```
image_id | table_id | table
-----------------------------
1        | 1        | user
2        | 1        | user

3        | 2        | user
4        | 2        | user

5        | 1        | product
6        | 1        | product
7        | 1        | product

8        | 2        | product

9        | 3        | product
10       | 3        | product

11       | 4        | product
```

Now the question is:

**Is this database design advised? What's the best approach to this request?**

Of course the other way is to have `user_image`, `product_image` and `company_image` tables instead of a single `image_table` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because then you lose the advantage of foreign keys.

Use junction tables:

```
create table product (
  product_id bigserial primary key,
  name citext not null unique
);

create table user (
  user_id bigserial primary key,
  name citext not null unique
);

-- personally, I would store the file in the db and use incremental backups
-- pedantically, I prefer "picture" over "image" as "image" has 2 meanings in computers
create table picture (
  picture_id bigserial primary key,
  filename citext not null,
  ...
);

create table product_picture (
  product_id bigint references product(product_id),
  picture_id bigint references picture(picture_id),
  primary key (product_id, picture_id)
);

create table user_picture (
  user_id bigint references user(user_id),
  picture_id bigint references picture(picture_id),
  primary key (user_id, picture_id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you. But about the second sentence, according to the request, we don't have `many-to-many` relationship. That's a simple `one-to-many`. This way I think that I shouldn't use `many-to-many` design and **junction tables** accordingly. How you feel about that? _It's important for me to know your idea back about my comment. (Of course you look more experienced)._

Comment: As the second question, this looks to me much more bothering. Three tables for users, companies, and products means of three sets of `controller`s, `model`s, _(but not `view`s because images will be loaded in detail views of their parent entities)_. What if another entity needed to have images like the prev 3 ones? And from the other aspect, I should say that I haven't used foreign keys until now (and had no problem). Generally is that a shame using foreign keys, not?

Comment: updated my answer. you will have to update your models, but shouldn't have to add more controllers.

Comment: Thank you Very much. Also, you are right. With this schema, even controllers shouldn't be added.